# Using valgrind to debug a PHP cli segmentation fault

Tags: php, debugging, valgrind

I have a third-party `PHP` script that I am running in the `cli` and it is throwing a `segmentation fault`, which I am trying now to debug.

Just learned about the `valgrind` tool, but most of the guides I can find seem to be for `PHP` running in `Apache`, not the `cli`.

How can I use `valgrind` to debug my `cli` script and figure out what is causing this `segmentation fault`?

**EDIT:**

Using help from @sudowned it gave me the following, but not sure what it is telling me:

```
==32363== Invalid read of size 8
==32363==    at 0x6A459A: _zend_mm_alloc_canary_int (in /usr/bin/php5)
==32363==    by 0x6A4CFD: _zend_mm_realloc_canary_int (in /usr/bin/php5)
==32363==    by 0x690CC3: zend_hash_do_resize (in /usr/bin/php5)
==32363==    by 0x6925C7: _zend_hash_add_or_update (in /usr/bin/php5)
==32363==    by 0x68EA1F: add_assoc_zval_ex (in /usr/bin/php5)
==32363==    by 0x69729D: zif_get_defined_constants (in /usr/bin/php5)
==32363==    by 0xE393B63: ??? (in /usr/lib/php5/20090626/suhosin.so)
==32363==    by 0x6D4B15: zend_do_fcall_common_helper_SPEC (in /usr/bin/php5)
==32363==    by 0x6ABD8F: execute (in /usr/bin/php5)
==32363==    by 0xE394115: ??? (in /usr/lib/php5/20090626/suhosin.so)
==32363==    by 0x6D4805: zend_do_fcall_common_helper_SPEC (in /usr/bin/php5)
==32363==    by 0x6ABD8F: execute (in /usr/bin/php5)
==32363==  Address 0x1c486147 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==32363== 
==32363== 
==32363== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==32363==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x1C486147
==32363==    at 0x6A459A: _zend_mm_alloc_canary_int (in /usr/bin/php5)
==32363==    by 0x6A4CFD: _zend_mm_realloc_canary_int (in /usr/bin/php5)
==32363==    by 0x690CC3: zend_hash_do_resize (in /usr/bin/php5)
==32363==    by 0x6925C7: _zend_hash_add_or_update (in /usr/bin/php5)
==32363==    by 0x68EA1F: add_assoc_zval_ex (in /usr/bin/php5)
==32363==    by 0x69729D: zif_get_defined_constants (in /usr/bin/php5)
==32363==    by 0xE393B63: ??? (in /usr/lib/php5/20090626/suhosin.so)
==32363==    by 0x6D4B15: zend_do_fcall_common_helper_SPEC (in /usr/bin/php5)
==32363==    by 0x6ABD8F: execute (in /usr/bin/php5)
==32363==    by 0xE394115: ??? (in /usr/lib/php5/20090626/suhosin.so)
==32363==    by 0x6D4805: zend_do_fcall_common_helper_SPEC (in /usr/bin/php5)
==32363==    by 0x6ABD8F: execute (in /usr/bin/php5)
==32363==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==32363==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==32363==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==32363==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==32363==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==32363== 
==32363== HEAP SUMMARY:
==32363==     in use at exit: 180,903,362 bytes in 27,691 blocks
==32363==   total heap usage: 11,144,829 allocs, 11,117,138 frees, 2,198,841,176 bytes allocated
==32363== 
==32363== LEAK SUMMARY:
==32363==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==32363==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==32363==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==32363==    still reachable: 180,903,362 bytes in 27,691 blocks
==32363==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==32363== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==32363== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes
==32363== 
==32363== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==32363== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 37 from 10)
```

Comment: If you don't have PHP compiled with debugging symbols, and valgrind isn't helping, and you're on Unix, try `strace php -f script.php a b c` (replacing script.php and a, b, and c with any arguments obviously).  Somewhere just above the segfault will likely show something of interest: path names, system call error codes, etc.

Comment: That seemed like it would help, but not exactly sure what I would be looking for. Seems like a lot of info that is not helpful was returned.

Comment: If you don't understand debugging, none of it will appear helpful. Unfortunately, if you can't debug C, using Valgrind to debug the PHP interpreter is likely to be a waste of your time.

Comment: Post the complete strace output somewhere and I can help.  Otherwise, if dealing with strace, egrep 'E\w*' might prove helpful, as errors all begin with "E".

Answer (score 4):

You can, as laid out in the [Valgrind quick-start guide](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html#quick-start.mcrun), chain your PHP CLI command as follows:

```
valgrind --leak-check=yes php -f filename.php args
```

In order to glean useful information from the output, you may need to recompile PHP with [debug symbols.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configure.about.php):

```
./configure --enable-debug
```

**Edit:** In response to your comments, please keep in mind that when you are using Valgrind you are **not** debugging your PHP script: you are debugging the PHP interpreter, which is the underlying C executable.

**This is not a task for the lighthearted.**

Without a strong understanding of C (and debugging it) you are going to have a hard time gleaning useful information about the situation from a stack trace.

Valgrind has told you exactly what function *in the interpreter* caused the segmentation fault. The next step would be to isolate the variables passed to the function at the time of the segfault. From there deep knowledge of how PHP code maps to the underlying C will be necessary before you can even identify what PHP instruction caused it.

The simple answer is to start commenting out lines of PHP until your segfault ceases to occur, and then play with the guilty line until you determine what not to do. Low tech? Sure. Effective, equally sure. You could also use xdebug, [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13079513/how-do-i-diagnose-this-php-segmentation-fault), which could provide more targeted information about the interpreted code.

Comment: That worked, and I updated my post with the results. Really not sure what it is telling me...