# try/catch segmentation fault in php

Tags: php, linux, symfony

We have an issue with php-mime-mail-parser throwing a segmentation fault importing emails on our symfony 3.4 application. Since its an automated process we want to be either notified or skip the importing of the particular email that causes the segmentation fault. Is it possible to try catch the segmentation fault in php? Linux version is CentOS 7.

Comment: Best to try and let us know, in theory you should be able to try catch anything, even if the error isn't caused by PHP itself, if the code fails to run it will go to the catch.

Comment: A segmentation fault is a very fatal error and kills the script completely. You won't be able to catch it.

Comment: @Moudi already tried and it doesnt work. should have phrased the question differently: is there any method other than try catch!

Comment: Thank you for that information, I would invest in configuring Xdebug and try to fix the bug, as the only way to stop it from happening is fixing the bug causing the segmentation fault.

Comment: @Moidi yes thats what I feared. Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13269679/6546935